# Best practice and technology to Offset anchor links

Tags: links, offsets

I am using anchor links in the Front Page of [this Website](http://latitud.dinamicaweb.net/).

They are in ACCUEIL, SPORTIVES, VOYAGES and CONTACT.

In order for the anchor links to land in the right place, below the menu upper bar, is to use a [50px division](http://latitud.dinamicaweb.net/img/50px-division.png). Nevertheless, the spaces between the title and the upper element are uneven; for example, the space over ACCUEIL is greater the space over SPORTIVES. If you navigate through the anchors, you will see the difference.

¿Any JavaScript technique to accomplish the offset without the need to use the css divisions, and therefore have more control with the inter element distances?

Thanks

Comment: seems to be working fine (same amount of pixels from the nav menu) on Chrome/OSX

Comment: Looks the same to me too.

Comment: Be very careful trying to force things to exact pixels. If any of your visitors is using a custom user stylesheet (i.e. enlarging the font on every site so they can read it) your layout will break. Also different browsers handle partial-pixel rounding differently so some browsers may end up 1 pixel off, looking odd. Far better to do your layouts with ems, rems, percentages, etc. that flex, so they're not fragile.